# Grappelli dashboard: change text in ModelList

Tags: django, django-grappelli

I'm creating a custom dashboard in Grappelli for Django. I wish to change the text that links to models in a basic ModelList.

My `dashboard.py` contains only this simple ModelList:

```
self.children.append(modules.ModelList(
    title=('My Model List'),
    column=1,
    models=('wedding.models.Event','wedding.models.Guest',),
))
```

How do I change the *text* rendered in this dashboard. Specifically, the text of the link to these two models—`wedding.models.Event` and `wedding.models.Guest`—? I am not referring to changing the title of the list.

To clarify my question: How do I specify the text of the links to these two models in this dashboard?

What approaches permit someone to have different text for these links for different custom dashboards which reference the same models?

Should I use some sort of "children" or tuple?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with grappelli, only with django admin.
add this code to your model class

```
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'mymodel'
        verbose_name_plural = 'mymodels'
```